# Does deploying a git repository to a live server overwrite the existing files?

Tags: git, ftp, bitbucket

Does deploying a repository to a live server overwrite the existing files there? Or does it just add the files from the repository?

The scenario: I'm setting up a git repository (using BitBucket and DeployHQ) to replace uploading files to a website via FTP.

The repository is connected to the server using DeployHQ, and I'm going to test with a simple "hello world" html file. Since the server has multiple domains, I don't want to accidentally deploy it to the wrong path and overwrite the live sites.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

when setting up deploying, I would always recommend to

- make sure everything you have on your live server is properly backed up and
- try it out on a test server.

I suppose a test server is not available in yo ur case, so, while still heeding the first advice, try the following:

I believe DeployHQ actually uses (s)FTP for deploying, which means it will transfer the files to the server like you are used to. It has an opt-in for deleting files, don't check that in first run.

Easiest I suppose would be so set up, like you suggest, a project with 1 file called "helloworld.html" or something unique and deploy that, check where on your server it ended up and then be confident about what directory it writes to.

Last but not least, they have a help desk to help you using a chat bubble. I would never hesitate to use such a service to my advantage and prevent any mistakes!